# Python script executes from terminal, but not when using subprocess?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm using `subprocess` to execute a Python script called trace.py that is located in a different folder. The script trace.py then uses subprocess to run a traceroute command and then prints the output. When I go to the folder that trace.py is located in and type this in the terminal:

```
python trace.py
```

or

```
./trace.py
```

or from any location:

```
python /home/.../cgi-bin/trace.py
```

it works fine and the traceroute is printed to the terminal. However, when I try to execute trace.py from main.py by using `subprocess`, it doesn't seem to work. I've tested this by creating test.py and using subprocess to execute it from main.py and this works. I do this with the following:

```
output = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, script_path])
```

Where `script_path` is the absolute path to `trace.py`.

The full error I get is this (paths are shortened):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/.../cgi-bin/trace.py", line 11, in <module>
traceroute = subprocess.check_output(["traceroute", "www.google.com"])
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 97, in <module>
serve(args.port, public_html, cgibin)
    File "main.py", line 55, in serve
process = subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/python", script_path])
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python', '/home/.../cgi-bin/trace.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Why does this not work, but executing it from the terminal does?

Comment: can print the output of `python trace.py --ip www.google.com ; echo $?`

Comment: The exit status is `1`. The terminal isn't interested. Try `echo $?` to see that it is `1`.

Comment: @PeterWood the exit status is 0.

Comment: Is it really `home/.../cgi-bin`. That `...` doesn't look right. What's the value of `script_path`?

Comment: Just a guess: maybe the trace.py script requires the current working directory to be where it is located (perhaps you import other modules that are otherwise not on sys.path).  Telling subprocess what directory to change to before executing may help.  Also, the output of the process that you didn't show may have the error from python that would explain why it exited with an error status.

Comment: @PeterWood I just removed some folders in between to make it shorter, script_path is the full path to trace.py so `/home/.../cgi-bin/trace.py` @dsh I don't think so, when I type `python /home/.../cgi-bin/trace.py` it executes it (I removed the command line arguments).

Comment: @dsh I added the full error message.

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`  There's the cause.  The path you specified is incorrect.

Comment: @dsh but it's not. When I print the path and use it in the terminal it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child can't find `traceroute` executable.

1. Compare `os.environ['PATH']` in your shell with the value within runnning `trace.py`
2. Check file permissions -- whether it is readable and executable by the user that runs `trace.py`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want me to do? Printing `os.environ["PATH"]` in a python shell in the terminal and printing it in `trace.py` prints the same thing.

Comment: @Esoemah: I've updated the answer. If the file permissions also look ok then create a *minimal* code example that demonstrates your issue and update your question e.g., `python -c'import subprocess, sys; subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-c", """import subprocess; subprocess.check_call(["mtr", "www.google.com"])"""])'
`

Comment: I figured it out thanks to you. It was the PATH like you said, so much struggle when it was something that simple...